# set default values in mysql Id column?

Tags: mysql

I want to start my mysql table id as todaysdate+000001 like 20120602000001 OR 20120602/000001 and that when next entry made then ID should be 20120602000002 OR 20120602/000002 (means it should get auto_incremented also).
HOw can we do this?

my table structure is

```
table abc(id int auto_increment,name varchar(50),company varchar(50),contact varchar(10),persontomeet varchar(30),intime TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,primary key(id));
```

but id starts with 1 obiviously..
I want to start it as 20120602000001 and when next time INSERT triger will trigger then it should get set to 20120602000002
please help me...

Comment: And what if the date changes to tomorrow!?

Comment: date will also change as we are storing todays date then when tommorow query will get fire it will catch that day's date

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 20120602000001
```

Comment: this is not sufficient.
above is my table structure
but that starts id like 1,2,3....
I want to store id as 20120604000001 but how that I don't know please help me?